# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'dest_address' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem inserting data into the DB.

The address box is filled with the exact address from the Google maps. I want to insert into DB, it is showing that my attribute is null.

[image: image of my blade]

I don't know to to pass the data from JS the blade or whatever is possible so that the attribute "dest_address" is not null.

**script.js**

```js
var map;
var myLatLng;
var searchBox;

$(document).ready(function() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 27.72,
      lng: 85.36
    },
    zoom: 15
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 27.72,
      lng: 85.36   
    },
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  searchBox = new google.maps.places
    .SearchBox(document.getElementById('dest_address'));

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var i, place;

    for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      //set marker position new
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setZoom(15);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {
    var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
    var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
  
    $('#lat').val(lat);
    $('#lng').val(lng);
  });
});
```

**DestinationAdd.blade.php**

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="dest_address" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="dest_address">
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

My controller is fine so far because I tried to insert the longitude and latitude first without inserting the address, and the longitude & latitude were in the DB.

Comment: You might want to have another attempt at specifying tags. This question has nothing to do with php or laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input dest_address hasn't name attribute.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="dest_address" name="dest_address">
```

remember ID attr is using only to identify HTML element but you need a name to receive data in the controller.

Please try this and let me know how it works :)